# Prove or disprove if $n$ is an odd integer then $n^2-1$ is divisible by 8

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Hey I'm stuck on this question on how to prove it, I can prove if it's divisible by $4$ but I'm unsure how to do it for $8$.

**Question**

Prove or disprove the following:

If n is an odd integer then $n^2-1$ is divisible by 8 (and 16 is the next question).

**Note**

I know they're true and false respectively but I'm not sure how to prove it, if you could show me how to do both that would be greatly appreciated!

**Working**

$n\in\mathbb{Z^{odd}} \implies n=2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore n^2-1=(2k+1)^2-1$

$= 4k^2+4k+1-1$

$=4k^2+4k$

$4(k^2+k)$

Since $4|8 \implies 4(k^2+k)|8$

$\therefore (n^2-1)|8$

QED

As you can see from the proof I can easily show that $(n^2-1)|4$ however I'm not sure what to do after it, as $4\nmid 8$ (I'm pretty sure)

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be writing divisibility backwards. Usually $a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: And to finish your proof, note that $k^2+k=k(k+1)$ is always even since one of $k$ or $k+1$ is even.

Comment: It is true that $4\mid 8$ ("four divides eight"), but only for very few $k$ does $4(k^2 + k)\mid 8$ (for instance, we do _not_ have $4\cdot(9+3)\mid 8$). Besides, you're not interested in numbers dividing $8$. You're interested in $8$ dividing other numbers. Therefore you need to check whether $8\mid 4(k^2 + k)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1.** $ \ $ Consider two cases:

(A) $ \ \  n=4k+1$,

(B) $ \ \  n=4k-1$.

Then $n^2-1=(16k^2 \pm 8k +1)-1 = 16k^2 \pm 8k$, which is clearly divisible by 8.

**Part 2.** $ \ $ Now let's prove that $n\in{\mathbb Z}^{\rm odd} \not\Rightarrow 16\,|\,(n^2-1)$. Consider $n=5$, then 
$$n^2-1=24 \equiv 8 \ ({\rm mod \ } 16),$$ and we  are done.

Answer (score 1):

Use congruences mod. $8$:

An odd integer $n$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ or $\pm 3 \bmod 8$. So $n^2\equiv 1^2=1$ or $3^2\equiv 2\bmod 8$. In both cases, $n^2-1\equiv0\mod 8$.

Comment: if you may pardon my nativity, I'm wondering how is it true that an odd integer **is** congruent to ±1 or ±3 mod 8 to be used as a starting premise for a proof?

Comment: I don't understand: what's the problem?

Comment: the first statement. How did you know it's a valid starting point to construct the proof? is it a fact, maybe?

Comment: It's rather natural: the statement to be proved asserts that if  $n$ is odd, the $n^2-1equiv 0\mod 8 $. So I enumerated the different  cases in the simplest possible way.

Comment: clear. upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

you are so close:

$4(k^2+k)$

$k^2 + k = k(k+1)$ and one of $k, k+1$ is even.

$8|4(k^2 +k)$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n$ is odd then there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2k+1$ so that
$$
n^2-1=(2k+1)^2-1=4k^2+4k=4k(k+1).
$$
And since either $k$ or $k+1$ is even for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ then $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ for any odd $n$.